# how to validate credit card number and Card Code Verification (ccv)

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

i am using authorize.net {aim} for payment gate way.

I have used http://www.johnconde.net/blog/tutorial-integrating-the-authorizenet-aim-api-with-php/ class and successfuly working without error.

But my client need to validate the ccv [Card Code Verification].

Can anyone please help with this.

I am using test authorize for developer account.

Thank You

Comment: Surely the CCV is checked by the gateway during the transaction? Why do you need to do anything with it?

Comment: i checked with the test credit card, for that all the ccv code was 123.but i need to confirm that with proper ccv code it won't work?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using their testing system?

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what you are actually asking. Leave card details to the payment gateway, it's what it is there for. You shouldn't be / have to do anything with any of the card details other than forward them along.

Comment: ok thank you ,i got it for test account they are not validating cvv code

Comment: Have done more research, and think I misunderstood. Please see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so after some initial fail on understanding what was being asked for, I think the following should help.

http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Validating-Credit-Card-Information-Part-3-of-3-CVV-Numbers/ba-p/7657

The post provides some code that validates a CVV number. It obviously can't tell you if it's correct or not though.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: thank you , but can i integrate this function to some other class.As i mention im using johncodone code

Comment: I'd do it straight after form submission. So before the stuff in the tutorial you linked to. On fail, send them back to the payment page, otherwise continue with what you've got. If that makes sense.